# Run-time error '424': Object Required

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am executing following VBA code and I got the run-time error saying that Object Required. I have tried all the suggested solutions online but couldn't solve the issue.

```
Sub connect()
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim Abbrevation As String
Dim Abbrev_Num As String
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'EBGen-Daily
Server_Name = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b2").Value
Database_Name = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b3").Value ' Name of database
User_ID = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b4").Value 'id user or username
Password = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b5").Value 'Password

Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'NEW STATEMENT
Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
myRow = 1
myCol = 7
Abbrevation = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, myCol)
myCol = myCol + 1
Abbrev_Num = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, myCol)

SQLStr = "INSERT INTO acct_abbr(abbrev,number) VALUES('" & Abbrevation & "', '" & Abbrev_Num & "');"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStr
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming `DoCmd` is a global object variable?

Comment: @PankajJaju [DoCmd is a built-in VBA object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223114%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

Comment: On which statement does the error occur? Are you familiar with how to debug VBA code?

Comment: Did you define `rs` and `cn` variables?

Comment: @rontornambe +1 I was typing your first question as a comment as your appeared.

Comment: DoCmd is an Access object.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - Didn't knew about it. Thanks. Not quite an Access VBA expert :-) I was wondering because I never saw any such thing in Excel. But then Jimmy mentioned that its because Excel don't really recognize DoCmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel doesn't recognize DoCmd.  Try this instead.

```
'DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStr
Cn.Execute (SQLStr)
```